Can we use single NAT gateway for inbound access to RDS and Opensearch resources in private subnet?
we have multiple resources like RDS Aurora and Opernsearch service nodes in private subnet of VPC. We would like to have access to those resources from internet. Is it possible to use single NAT gateway in public subnet to provide access to there resources? I know NAT gateways are used to provide outbound access to the resources in private subnet but is reverse possible since its a Network address translation router after all. We dont want to use jump hosts.
If not NAT gateway then any other service can be used?

A NAT Gateway is for outbound traffic only. NAT Gateways cannot be used to make private resources accessible from the Internet. If you want those resources to be accessible from the Internet you should place them in public subnets instead of private subnets.

Thanks for the answer but is there a no way to get that access without placing them in public subnets?

The entire point of placing things in a private subnet is to prevent them from being exposed to the Internet. You are doing a thing that specifically prevents things from being exposed to the Internet, and wanting them to be exposed to the Internet anyway. Either expose them to the Internet by placing them in public subnets, or look into other ways to access those resources, for example by running a VPN service in the VPC and connecting to the VPN.

can we use interface/gateway VPC endpoint services ?
